# SQL Server: Detect Non-Parameterized Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, security, parameterized-query, parameterization

I have a client which has had programming performed by past developers.  Their code has recently become suspect, and I'd like to know if they are using parameterized queries.  I was hoping I could detect non-parameterized requests through SQL Server, but I haven't found a way to do this.  I understand that not all queries need to be parameterized, since a query might be something like

```
select count(*) from Customers
```

But if SQL Server could tell me programmatically which queries have any string-constant inputs instead of parameter inputs, that would be great.
By the way, logging all SQL queries and removing all lines with the @ symbol is close, but the below query would then be considered legitimate:

```
select * from Users where Username='user' and Password=@Password
```

So I really need SQL Server to read into the content of the command and determine if all inputs are parameterized.  Thank you.

Comment: I gather the source code is not available to you. Which version of SQL Server is this?

Comment: There are legitimate use cases for string literals, if the literals are supplied by the programmer instead of the user.

Comment: How do you tell the last query in your example from `select * from Users where UserType='admin' and Username=@Username and Password=@Password`?

Comment: Check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/queryoptteam/archive/2006/03/31/565991.aspx) link!

Comment: @abhi, the source code is available in some cases, but there are so many sites.  It would take so long to comb through all the source code to look for these sorts of issues.  So I thought I should check SQL Server first.  It's SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, for the purpose of this check, I'm fine with false positives.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, this might be considered a false positive, but that's fine in this exercise.

Comment: @abhi, I'm sorry, but I don't understand how your link can help my situation.  Would you please provide some additional details?

Comment: Also, I know it's just an example, but that looks suspiciously like a plain-text password, which is nearly as bad of a problem as sql injection.

Comment: Well, depending upon how *many* false positives are ok... you might try `SELECT *  FROM [master].[sys].[syscacheobjects]  WHERE [sql] LIKE '%WHERE%''%'`, which would give you executed queries which have a single-quote anywhere after the `WHERE`.  Obviously, you can come up with variations of this, but I thought the `[sql]` column in the `[syscacheobjects]` system view could be helpful here.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, I'm not exactly sure why that's relevant to this thread.  Still, in this example, `@Password` would be populated with an encrypted, hashed, salted (etc.) password.

Comment: @Doug_Ivison, that's actually pretty helpful.  When do SQL queries get deleted from this table?  They aren't cached here forever, right?  I'm just wondering how far back this table allows me to see.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In fact you're searching for **adhoc** queries (not stored procedure and not sp_executesql).

You could start by having a look on `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans` DMV:

```
SELECT
    CP.usecounts
    , CP.cacheobjtype
    , ST.text as sql_Statement    
    , QP.query_plan
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_cached_plans CP
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(CP.plan_handle) ST
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(CP.plan_handle) QP
WHERE
    ST.dbid = DB_ID()
    AND CP.objtype IN ( 'Adhoc')
ORDER BY
    CP.usecounts DESC
```

Just be aware that Relational Engine could parametrize simple queries (feature called **simple parametrization**), so you might have same rows to

In case you want to achieve an improvement of performance by not caching plans for adhoc queries, there is a server option called `optimize for ad hoc workloads` that signals to Relational Engine that first time when a query is executed => to store a lighter version of the plan (plan stub).

Plan cache pollution could be also a reason for degrading database performance. Check [this query](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/how-to/view-state-plan-cache-verifying-plan-cache-pollution) to detect if it's your case also.

Answer (score 0):

Mihai is pointing you to the current system object, `dm_exec_cached_plans`.  (When I looked up an answer to your question, I found that `[syscacheobjects]` is actually deprecated.)  Therefore, I did upvote *his* answer.

However, I still think it could save you time, to check for a single quote after the `WHERE`.  Using `dm_exec_cached_plans`, here's a similar query, using a `WHERE` like I gave you before:

```
SELECT usecounts, cacheobjtype, objtype, text
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans 
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) 
WHERE [text] LIKE '%WHERE%''%'
----AND [text] NOT LIKE '%sp_executesql%'  ----queries probably ok, with sp_executesql
----WHERE usecounts > 1   ----un-commenting this might also be interesting to check out. 
ORDER BY usecounts DESC;
```

Or, just adding it to Mihai's query:

```
SELECT
    CP.usecounts
    , CP.cacheobjtype
    , ST.text as sql_Statement    
    , QP.query_plan
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_cached_plans CP
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(CP.plan_handle) ST
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(CP.plan_handle) QP
WHERE
    CP.objtype = 'Adhoc'
    AND ST.dbid = DB_ID()
    AND ST.text LIKE '%WHERE%''%'
ORDER BY
    CP.usecounts DESC
```

Note the `ORDER BY`, built on the thought that the commonly occurring queries are causing frequent exposure.  But as you probably already realize... if the suspect code is building the query strings itself, then unique values (like row numbers or customer ids or order numbers, etc.) could produce unique queries that, (if they were built without using `sp_executesql`), could actually be the **most** important to look at, even though they have `usecounts = 1`.

As far as the answer to your question goes, ("When do SQL queries get deleted from this table?"):  once there are enough queries in the cache to cause "memory pressure," old queries drop out of the cache as new queries come in... and all of it is cleared when SQL restarts.  (See http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1375781-391-1.aspx and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Hope that helps...

Comment: **Regarding usecounts=1**: In fact, plan cache pollution is related to a lot of query plans cached with usecounts=1 as SQL Server considers that ahhoc query is different no matter the values of the parameters have been changed. Even more, any comment or carriage return in an adhoc query leads to a new generated plan (except simple parametrization case, which should not appear so often in a production environment)!